# Encrypting the password using salt in c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, password-protection

I searched for some code for doing that, but found some with pre defined salt. I want to auto generate the salt for each user and store the salt value in the table. Thanks I am new to programming please help

Comment: What is the question exactly? You seem to have a handle on exactly what you need to do.

Comment: "I am new to programming" and ANY question to do with encryption should set off an alarm bell. Encryption is such a hard task to get right, I would be very, very cautious about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**(As suggested, I've replaced my previous salt generation method with something that should be more secure)**

To generate a random salt:

```
public static string GenerateRandomSalt(RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng, int size)
{
    var bytes = new Byte[size];
    rng.GetBytes(bytes);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
var salt1 = GenerateRandomSalt(rng, 16);
var salt2 = GenerateRandomSalt(rng, 16);
// etc.
```

`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is used to generate "cryptographically strong random values," making it more suitable for use here than the standard `Random` class.  However you generate the salt, you can then append it to your password and hash using your algorithm of choice:

```
var salt = GenerateRandomSalt(rng, 16);
var hashedPassword = DoPasswordHashing(password + salt);
```

However, it's worth pointing out that doing user authentication correctly can be a more difficult problem than it seems.  Eric Lippert wrote a series of blog articles about this several years ago:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/01/28/you-want-salt-with-that-part-one-security-vs-obscurity.aspx

Comment: Do not use Random for *any* task involving cryptography; it is not designed to be cryptographically secure. The attack here would be that a rainbow table generator would concentrate on those salts likely to be generated by Random, greatly reducing the size of the table that the attacker needs to generate. **A salt has to be cryptographically random in order to be useful.**

Comment: This is, of course, true, and I suppose I should have taken the time to provide a more correct demonstration.  This is the purpose of the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class, correct?

Comment: @ColeCampbell yes RNGCryptoServiceProvider is best to use here.