# Locking for CryptoJS.lib.WordArray alternative in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptojs, salt

i'm locking for an alternative of CryptoJS.lib.WordArray in C#, exactly WordArray.random that generate random salt for encryption ([see_more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718868/not-having-the-same-result-between-aes-of-javascript-cryptojs-and-aes-c-sharp-ri?noredirect=1#comment121455144_68718868)).

```
if (!salt) {
                salt = WordArray.random(64/8);
            }
```

this code is from cryptojs/cipher-core.js

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I generate a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668353/how-can-i-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-pseudorandom-number-in-c)

Comment: Do they have the same behavior ? _Wordarray_ code is available but not _RNGCryptoServiceProvider_ .

Comment: `WordArray` is a type that CryptoJS uses _internally_. For what do you need a `WordArray` in C#? With `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random()` you create (pseudo) random data in CryptoJS. The counterpart in C# is e.g. `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.